# Web Navigation Patterns Mining / Network Clustering Algorithm/Approach for web traffic clustering

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis, graph-algorithm

I have the following problem:

I have a list of web pages represented as vertices v0, v1, ... , vN.

I have graphs g0, g1, ... , gM which have edge lists which show pages visited by a user during a visit to the website such as:

1. g0:      (v3, v44) ; (v44, v5)
2. g1:      (v3, v44) ; (v44, v5) ; (v5, v7)
3. ...
4. gM: ...

I am looking to use this data to develop clusters of web page visitation patterns.

I'm looking for:
1. Papers, blogs, etc. to algorithms that can help me solve this problem.
2. open source code, code fragments that tackle this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Note:

I am aware of and use Graph Clustering Algorithms. I was looking for something specific to this application.

Comment: `g0` to `gM` are `M+1` visits (paths) on the same graph? What does visitation pattern mean? some vertices in a row?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data actually includes hyper-edges between users, webpages, and other webpages as well as a temporal factor. There is some research on tensor factorization that might address these types of problems, but it will probably be better to discard one of the edge dimensions and/or the time component to take advantage of better-researched approaches.

Here are two potential methods:

1. You could look only at the edges between webpages and analyze the
   clicked-links using a stochastic block model. Eric Xing has some
   interesting work on this:
   http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/papers/2009/fu_song_xing_icml09.pdf.
2. You could look only at which webpages were accessed by different users
   (throw out the links between webpages) and use a collaborative
   filtering (http://www2.research.att.com/~volinsky/netflix/) or a
   co-clustering approach (google "coclustering").